# Problema de validación, índice fuera de rango

Tags: c#, mvc, model-view-controller

Estoy con `mvc c#` tratando de validar. El problema está en que si ingreso un número que no exista en la `bd` me sale el error de que está fuera del índice de intervalo. Así lo estoy validando:

```
if (persona[0]?.titulo == null || persona[0].titulo == 0
                    || persona330[0]?.titulo == null || persona330[0].titulo == 0
                    || persona.Count <=0)//aquí es donde sale el error de índice
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, el título ingresado no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
```

Resto del código:

```
public ActionResult Pdf(double? titulo)
        {
            try
            {
                ConexionSql sql = new ConexionSql();
                ConexionSQL330 sql330 = new ConexionSQL330();

                var persona = sql.cargarDatosPDF(titulo);
                var persona330 = sql330.cargarDatosPDF(titulo);

                //inline para verlo online, attachment para descarga directa

                if (titulo > persona[0]?.titulo || persona[0]?.titulo == null || persona[0].titulo == 0
                    || titulo > persona[0]?.titulo || persona330[0]?.titulo == null || persona330[0].titulo == 0
                    || persona.Count <=0)
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, el título ingresado no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }

                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + titulo + "-" + persona[0].cantCuotas + ".pdf\"");

            //resto código
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                return Content("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué no funciona? -o, ¿A dónde le estoy errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La construcción de tu condición asume que `persona` tiene al menos un elemento y el mensaje de error te indica que está vacío.

Mi sugerencia es validarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
if( persona == null || persona.count == 0 )
{
   // coloca aquí las instrucciones de lo que ocurre cuando persona es nulo o vacío
}
else
{
    if (titulo > persona[0]?.titulo || persona[0]?.titulo == null || persona[0].titulo == 0
                    || titulo > persona[0]?.titulo || persona330[0]?.titulo == null 
                    || persona330[0].titulo == 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, el título ingresado no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
}
```

Comment: Pues, me gustaría pero en esta línea `persona == null || persona == 0` el error está en que no se puede utilizar el operador `==` en list o int

Comment: Si la escribiste en el programa tal como está en el comentario, te faltó el `.count` en `persona.count == 0`

Comment: Listo, la solución fue como dijiste pero añadiendo el `.Count` quedando `persona.Count == null || persona.Count == 0`

Comment: Por favor revisa bien, la primera condicion es `persona == null` el `.count` va en la segunda